# Docker caching outside /var/lib/docker?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

Does Docker keep any data outside `/var/lib/docker` directory?

Seems so, because my fresh `docker-compose`, having a new mysql container named as one of my old mysql containers, keeps recreating the old one (regardless the `--force-recreate` option). And it happens even after `docker.io` reinstall!

Anyone have an idea where to look for traces of Docker outside its main directory?

This is the part of my `docker-compose` and the service that keeps being recreated with old environment.

```
db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wrojees09
    volumes:
      - /home/db:/var/lib/mysql
```

I tried to change the mysql version and after that I'm getting `InnoDB: Unsupported redo log format. The redo log was created with MySQL 8.0.20.` - deleting logs at `/var/lib/mysql` and `docker.io` reinstall didn't work, so there is definately some place Docker keeps some information outside, but where?

Comment: Docker doesn't keep anything outside that directory.

Comment: So then how come even reinstall didn't help in both of my cases?

Comment: I don't know what you did and how. Docker doesn't keep ANYTHING outside of that directory.

Comment: You bind mount a `/home/db` host directory as the database data directory; are you clearing out that directory when you switch versions?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you so much, it was so simple and I lost 2 days on that! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you bind-mount host content into your containers, that will generally be outside `/var/lib/docker`, and will persist even across fairly hard resets of Docker content.

You have a mounted host directory:

```
volumes:
  - /home/db:/var/lib/mysql
```

When you change MySQL versions the content in that directory will get reused.